# How to print and format function that is used in server.R file

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build shiny app that does some easy calculation and prints both, result of that calculation and function. Below snippet of the code. What I expect is to see in main panel in line 1 - `sqrt("value that is selected by user")`
line 2 - result of sqrt("value that is selected by user")

**server.R**

```
function(input, output) {
  output$textFunction1 <- renderText({sqrt(input$element1)})
}
```

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(navbarPage('navbar', tabPanel(
  'tabpanel',
  sidebarLayout(
    position = "left",
    sidebarPanel(
      "X",
      width = 4,
      sliderInput(
        'element1',
        label = 'alpha',
        min = 1         ,
        max = 10,
        value = 1,
        step = 1
      )
    ),
    mainPanel("main panel", width = 8,
              fluidRow(
                textOutput("textFunction1", container = pre),
                fluidRow(textOutput("textFunction1", container = pre))
     )))
)))
```

Thanks

Comment: There are some example of what you are trying to do, maybe this should help you. http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/mathjax.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. Only few changes check below, w.r.t `textFunction1`and the how you render it. As mentioned in comments, if you are looking for some mathematical expression display in `Line 1` check these [examples](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/mathjax.html). To render the equations properly in you need to view the result in a web browser. 
Check changes in the below code w.r.t to your above question

```
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$textFunction1 <- renderPrint({input$element1 })
  output$textFunction2 <- renderText({sqrt(input$element1)})
}

ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage('navbar', tabPanel(
  'tabpanel',
  sidebarLayout(
    position = "left",
    sidebarPanel(
      "X",
      width = 4,
      sliderInput(
        'element1',
        label = 'alpha',
        min = 1         ,
        max = 10,
        value = 1,
        step = 1
      )
    ),
    mainPanel("main panel", width = 8,
              fluidRow(
                textOutput("textFunction1", container = pre),
                textOutput("textFunction2", container = pre)
              )))
)))


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```